# What's the formal difference between analytical and numerical?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

While trying to wrap my head around differential equations in a practical way, I found a quite enlightening phrase about it

> Solving a differential equation can be done in three major ways:
>   analytical, qualitative, and numerical.
>
> source : http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/phaseline/phaseline.html

Now forget about differential equations: what's the formal definition of *analytical* and *numerical* ?

For example, another case where the numerical case looks the same as the analytical one is the following, consider the equation for the generic straight line

$$y = mx + q$$

$m$ has the same value generated by the analytical concept of derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$, infact the value of the first derivative can be generally used to determine the slope of a line . The first solution is numerical, the second is analytical .

Hoping that this parallel example is fitting and correct, and although I think I intuitively get the difference between a numerical and an analytical solution/approach, I would like a formal definition that can help me distinguish between the 2 in any case, with any math tool .

Comment: @Amzoti quite general definitions, for example back to my _derivative_ example, I would like to add a third case to calculate the slope with $tan(x)$, now is this a numerical or an analytical approach ? And why ?

Comment: What's the downvote about ?

Comment: @Amzoti Indeed, but I still can't associate the _trigonometric case_ to 1 of the 2 choices and motivate that choice. I also would like to improve my question if there is something wrong with it .

Answer (score 1):

Referring to differential equations:

1)the analytical approach is about trying to prove the existence, the uniqueness and find an explicit form for the solution.

As finding an explicit form is almost always very difficult (or impossible) one can go through two different ways

2)the numerical approach is about trying to find an approximate solution using algorithms of the numerical analysis.

3)the qualitative approach is about finding some proprieties of the solution without knowing it. For example we can say where is increasing, if is bounded ..etc

Comment: so back to my first post with the example & my comment with the question about $tan(x)$, in your opinion $tan(x)$ is what for that given problem ? An analytical or numerical solution ? Can you offer a brand new example ?

Comment: I haven't understand very well your example. What you have and what you want to compute?

Comment: Anyway I give you another example: Consider the linear system $Ax=b$, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},b\in\mathbb{R}^n$. The problem is to find one $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ which solves the system.
The analytical approach is, once proved that the system have a unique solution ($det(A)\neq 0$), find the exact solution $x=A^{-1}b$.
As this might take a long time (if $n$ is very big), exist some algorithms for finding an approximate sol: tis is the numerical approach.
The qualitative approach is saying some proprieties on the solution without knowing it, like in this case estimate the norm $||x||$.

Comment: However there are not a formal definitions for analytic/numerical/qualitative approach. They are concept that help you to understood what we are talking about and nothing more.

Comment: `there are not a formal definitions for there are not a formal definitions for analytic/numerical/qualitative approach/numerical/qualitative approach` so a mathematician can look at something and say _it's numerical_, another one can say _no it's analytical_ ? Plus you just gave your definition of _analytical_, so there is something to talk about .

Comment: I mean that saying numerical and analytical it's not like saying function or derivative, this two are concepts that have formal definition.If it can help you to understand, using a analytical approach to solve a problem is trying to solve it using the methods of the mathematical analysis http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_analysis. On the other hand the numerical approach use the methods of the numerical analysis http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis

Comment: ok, so the problem that I was mentioning before can be summarized as _find the slope of a straight line_, and I mentioned 3 possible way to do that. Now take the $tan(x)$ example, trigonometry is usually not considered part of math analysis, it's considered more like a set of rules and proportions that come from the observation of some nice properties of the _unit circle_, things that are not necessarily linked to the axioms of math analysis. So if $tan$ is not analytical, it's automatically a numerical solution ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17996/discussion-between-foo90-and-user2485710).

Comment: sorry I wasn't here for the chat; but I think that a final word is possible on this given the problem I'm proposing .